# Should there be a comma prior to a name as in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> This is Tara's son, Jonathan.

(or)

> This is Tara's son Jonathan.

I believe that there should be a comma.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but in English you'd use "my son" rather than use your own name. In other languages it is common to use names but English prefers pronouns when possible.

Comment: There are many, many resources that discuss the use of commas in English. What did you learn from the resources that you consulted?

Comment: Consider the possible ambiguity for the statements. Are you introducing Tara's son (called Jonathan) to someone else, or are you introducing Tara's son **to** Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Someone is introducing your son to someone who knows nothing about your family and telling them his name.

> This is Tara's son, [named] Jonathan.

The person already knows that you have a son called Jonathan, but hasn't met him before.

> This is Tara's son Jonathan.

Of course, the presence or absence of the comma would only matter in written dialogue.

Comment: It *may* have some relevance (I dunno), but I don't think it's exactly "central" whether the *audience* already have any prior knowledge of the referent. When someone exclaims *That's my son John over there!* it's extremely unlikely there'd be any pauses around the name - regardless of whether the speaker has *other* sons with different names, OR whether the audience know anything at all about the speaker and his family. And imho, the relevant rule is always "No pause, no comma".